# How to use Get-AnsibleParam, built-in function in Ansible

Tags: powershell, ansible

As the tile said, i would like to know the way to use this Get-AnsibleParam function. More specific, how to apply Get-AnsibleParam in this case:

i have a YAML file that contained some variables

```
---
type: taskWindows
actions:
  abortActions: []
  emailNotifications: []
  setVariableActions: []
  snmpNotifications: []
  systemOperations: []
agent: test
name: "Test"
summary: "Test"
...
```

I have a Powershell Script:

```
function Stonebrach.Connect {
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Sb_uri,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Auth_filename,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Method,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    $Body
)

$basicAuth=Get-Content "C:\$auth_filename"
$headers = @{
        "Authorization" = $basicAuth
        "Content-Type"="application/json"
}
$RSP=$null

try{
    if ( $body -eq $null ) {
        $response = invoke-restmethod -Uri $Sb_uri -Method $Method -Headers $headers
    }
    else {
        $response = invoke-restmethod -Uri $sb_uri -Method $method -Headers $headers -Body **$body**
    }
    return $response
}
catch{
   $RSP = $_.Exception.Message
   return $RSP
}
}

function Stonebranch.Create.Task.Windows {
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Sb_base_uri,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Auth_filename,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Method,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Body
)
    Stonebrach.Connect -SB_uri $Sb_base_uri/task -Auth_filename 
$Auth_filename -Method $Method -Body $Body
}
```

**Can i use Get-AnsibleParam to get the variables from YAML file (all of them) into the $body in the PS script in this case?** I tried to read the documentation, but it is not very clear how to use the function:

https://code.vt.edu/nis-ansible-roles/upstream-ansible/blob/2a751e1753c1fe675ba3d0b1dbc9939c9253ea70/lib/ansible/module_utils/powershell.ps1

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Get-AnsibleParam` is used to access specific parameter passed to a module. You can't use it to get all variables from your playbooks.

Take a look at [win_ping](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.5/lib/ansible/modules/windows/win_ping.ps1) for example usage:

```
$params = Parse-Args $args -supports_check_mode $true

$data = Get-AnsibleParam -obj $params -name "data" -type "str" -default "pong"

if ($data -eq "crash") {
    throw "boom"
}
```

In this case `win_ping` can accept parameter named `data` of type `string` with default value `pong`.